# How to automate Laravel backups on Windows?

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a web app using Laravel (using MySQL as the DB engine) but I'm using Windows in the server. There's a package called Laravel Backups but it's not compatible with Windows. The ideal would be to backup using the filesystems.